# Unable to have a Vim-like keybinding in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to replace the command for moving between windows in Emacs to

```
Ctrl-t
```

**The command in pseudo-code**

```
(global-set-key "\C-moveBetweenWindows" 'C-t)
```

**How can you remap the command for moving between windows in Emacs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `~/.emacs` file, include the following line:

```
(global-set-key "\C-t" 'other-window)
```

This will set `Ctrl-t` (`C-t`) to move to the next window just like the `C-x o` key sequence. This will replace the `transpose-chars` key binding, which you could set to something else if you wanted.